# How to run a crontab as another user

Tags: cron

I want to have a scheduled crontab run on a daily basis but not as the root user.
Reasons being that this is a simple backup and cleanup job and I don't want any accidents.
The backup folder will have permissions for user '`mysql-backup`' (for example) and I want the crontab to only run as user `mysql-backup`.  Obviously I don't want the mysql-backup user logged in or anything like that for the crontab to work.

Answer (score 6):

You can either edit the desired user's crontab:

```
crontab -e -u mysql-backup
```

or use `su` or `sudo` to change to that user at runtime in root's crontab.

Answer (score 2):

run `sudo crontab -u <user> -e`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're root, you can just su to the user, and create a crontab.

That should work.

Something like this should work fine.

<strike>su kyle -c "crontab -e"</strike>

*whistles to himself*

crontab -u kyle -e

Obviously that's what I meant.

Since it wasn't explicitly answered, a user does not have to be a normal user, or have login rights, or anything like that to have a working crontab.

Answer (score 0):

For system crontab, `/etc/crontab`, the 6th field is the user. For the crontab used by the user run `crontab -e` as that user and edit it's crontab. The crontab for users is stored in `/var/spool/cron/<username>`